# select distinct rows - distinct on all columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

how do we get the distinct rows - that is distinct by all columns - without specifying the column names individually

input

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
1  2    3    4    5
1  2    3    4    5
1  2    4    3    5
```

output

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
1  2    3    4    5
1  2    4    3    5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Select Distinct Row Based On Multiple Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695553/how-to-select-distinct-row-based-on-multiple-fields)

Comment: `Select Distinct *`?  What you're describing is exactly what `DISTINCT` does...

Comment: @SaggingRufus - this question is for postgres